# How can I prove that the cadinality of a set minus a finite number of elements of it is still the same as the original set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

A is a finite subset of S, which is an infinite set.

How can I prove that $|S| = |S \setminus A|$?

I just finished proving that $|T \cup S|$ where $T$ is infinite and $S$ is countable is $|T|$. They seem related but I can't solve it because I am confused by the concepts.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you proved that $|T\cup S| = |T|$ if $|T|$ is infinite and $|S|$ is countable, you can consider the identity $$S = (S\setminus A)\cup A.$$
Here, $A$ is countable (because it's finite), and $S\setminus A$ is infinite (because if it were finite then so would be $S$). By your identity, 
$$|S| = |S\setminus A|.$$

**In general,** if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint then $|X \cup Y| = |X| + |Y|$. When not both summands are finite, cardinal addition breaks down into taking maxes: $$|X| + |Y| = \max\{|X|, |Y|\}.$$
In your situation, let $X = S\setminus A$ and let $Y = A$.